# How to determine the load of a Sybase server from a script

Tags: load, sybase, sap-ase

I have to run stored procedures with different arguments a couple of times (10 000+) on a [sybase](/questions/tagged/sybase) server. I would like to launch the queries in parallel from a script. Before starting a new query I would like to determine the load of the Sybase server to decide automatically and dynamically how many queries can be launched in parallel.

Now I count the average response time of the queries and if it grows too high, then I stop starting new query, if it is lower than a predefined value then I can start more queries. But it is very dependent on the stored procedure and sometimes even on the arguments passed to it, so I would like to get some more objective measures similarly to the Linux load average returned by `cat /proc/loadavg` (`uptime`, `top`). `Gmake` has a similar feature to run in parallel and start a new process only if the load average is less then a specified value (see `-j` and `-l` options).

Is there a way to get some metric which correlates to the server's actual load?

I'm not an administrator and I'm launching the queries remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I found a stored procedure which can provide a lot of detailed information about the system load of a particular [sysbase](/questions/tagged/sysbase) server. It is called [sp_sysmon](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/sprocs207.htm).

It provides a lot of information. Some of them may be useful. The only issue I could find that the user need SA role to run this stored procedure.

An example (this prints almost all statistics):

```
sp_sysmon "00:01:00", noclear, @applmon = appl_and_login
```

It provides information about all "Engines" belong to the Sybase server, Network traffic, Disk I/O (even per device), Worker Process, Parallel Query, Task Context Switches, Task, Buffers, Transactions, Indices, Locks, Data Cache, Memory etc.

The output can be reduced adding different arguments to it. I have to play a little bit with it, but it seems a pretty cool tool.

It seems the 'sa_role' problem also can be solved (Description [Granting SA rights to non-SA users](http://www.sypron.nl/grant_sa.html), Source: [grant_sa.sql](http://www.sypron.nl/grant_sa.sql)).

But of course there is a drawback. [Documentation](http://www.lcard.ru/~nail/sybase/perf/28256.htm) states:

> sp_sysmon contributes 5 to 7 percent overhead while it runs on a
>   single CPU server, and more on multiprocessor servers. The amount of
>   overhead increases with the number of CPUs.